# Rescue light red Time Machine backups after El Capitan Update

Tags: time-machine, backup, restore, time-capsule, data-recovery

Here is my story:

- Oct 2: I have Yosemite Installed and configured Time Capsule taking regular backups.
- Oct 3: I update Yosemite to El Capitan
- El Capitan installation halts at 14% for 2hrs
- I force-restart my machine several times but the update never goes through
- I format my primary OSX partition and want to setup my mac again.
- I start recovery process from boot
- try to find my time machine but it shows my ONLY FULL Backup is 18th Sep (which is not what I want)
- I use the same, restore using that 18th Sep backup.
- When the restore process completes, my MAC is somehow updated to El Capitan with my data from 18th Sep backup
- Now I configure my Time Machine again, it shows my last backup of 4th Oct but its light-red bar (slowly blinking from very light to light red bar)
- I can't seem to access that 2nd Oct backup

Can anyone share if they have felt same, attaching screenshots for reference.
[image: The Backup I want with light-red bar]

[image: The backups I can see after my update and setting up of Time Machine]

Comment: You don't need a specific full backup to restore from, it will restore to the last incremental; that's the whole point of incremental backups.

Comment: Full probably means complete (as in run successfully) here, and the red one didn't complete and is unrecoverable.

Comment: I _think_ those bars have been red since Yosemite; before Yose, they were purple. It's glowing because you have your mouse cursor hovering on it. Just FYI, next time you do an OS X install or upgrade, push ⌘+L to open the log and see if it's still working. I do this every time now. Often, the progress bar seems stopped (even for several hours), but the log will have messages scrolling by to assure you it's still working. …Or, at the very least, you can see that there are no errors and the install is probably still progressing.

Comment: So guys, does this mean that backup is lost ? anyway I can recover. And thanks for the advice for next install but pls help me out if there is anything that can be done to recover now ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Hit “enter Time Machine”
2. Press the key combination shift-command-C
3. Then (very important) select a red bar to go back in time
   Explanation: dull red bars represent backups you cannot access, bright red bars you can
4. Then from Macintosh HD navigate to desired folder you want to restore
   Backups will now be accessible and you can select the folder you want to restore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a Finder copy. Open the drive and navigate to the volume date & directory that you are interested in.